# Kafka connection refused with Kubernetes nodeport

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to expose KAFKA in my Kubernetes setup for external usage using node port.

My Helmcharts kafka-service.yaml is as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka
  namespace: test
  labels:
    app: kafka-test
    unit: kafka
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: test-app
    unit: kafka
    parentdeployment: test-kafka
  ports:
    - name: kafka
      port: 9092
      targetPort: 9092
      nodePort: 30092
      protocol: TCP
```

kafka-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafka
  namespace: {{ .Values.test.namespace }}
  labels:
    app: test-app
    unit: kafka
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-app
        unit: kafka
        parentdeployment: test-kafka
    spec:
      hostname: kafka
      subdomain: kafka
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: {{ .Values.test.groupID }}
      containers:
        - name: kafka
          image: test_kafka:{{ .Values.test.kafkaImageTag }}
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
          env:
            - name: IS_KAFKA_CLUSTER
              value: 'false'
            - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
              value: zookeeper:2281
            - name: KAFKA_LISTENERS
              value: SSL://:9092
            - name: KAFKA_KEYSTORE_PATH
              value: /opt/kafka/conf/kafka.keystore.jks
            - name: KAFKA_TRUSTSTORE_PATH
              value: /opt/kafka/conf/kafka.truststore.jks
            - name: KAFKA_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: kafka-secret
                  key: jkskey
            - name: KAFKA_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: kafka-secret
                  key: jkskey
            - name: KAFKA_LOG_DIRS
              value: /opt/kafka/data
            - name: KAFKA_ADV_LISTENERS
              value: SSL://kafka:9092
            - name: KAFKA_CLIENT_AUTH
              value: none
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/opt/kafka/conf"
              name: kafka-conf-pv
            - mountPath: "/opt/kafka/data"
              name: kafka-data-pv
      volumes:
        - name: kafka-conf-pv
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: kafka-conf-pvc
        - name: kafka-data-pv
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: kafka-data-pvc
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app
      unit: kafka
      parentdeployment: test-kafka
```

zookeeper service yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
  namespace: {{ .Values.test.namespace }}
  labels:
    app: test-ra
    unit: zookeeper
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: test-ra
    unit: zookeeper
    parentdeployment: test-zookeeper
  ports:
    - name: zookeeper
      port: 2281
```

zookeeper deployment yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
  namespace: {{ .Values.test.namespace }}
  labels:
    app: test-app
    unit: zookeeper
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-app
        unit: zookeeper
        parentdeployment: test-zookeeper
    spec:
      hostname: zookeeper
      subdomain: zookeeper
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: {{ .Values.test.groupID }}
      containers:
        - name: zookeeper
          image: test_zookeeper:{{ .Values.test.zookeeperImageTag }}
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2281
          env:
            - name: IS_ZOOKEEPER_CLUSTER
              value: 'false'
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_SSL_CLIENT_PORT
              value: '2281'
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_DATA_DIR
              value: /opt/zookeeper/data
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_DATA_LOG_DIR
              value: /opt/zookeeper/data/log
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_KEYSTORE_PATH
              value: /opt/zookeeper/conf/zookeeper.keystore.jks
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: zookeeper-secret
                  key: jkskey
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_TRUSTSTORE_PATH
              value: /opt/zookeeper/conf/zookeeper.truststore.jks
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: zookeeper-secret
                  key: jkskey
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/opt/zookeeper/data"
              name: zookeeper-data-pv
            - mountPath: "/opt/zookeeper/conf"
              name: zookeeper-conf-pv
      volumes:
        - name: zookeeper-data-pv
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: zookeeper-data-pvc
        - name: zookeeper-conf-pv
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: zookeeper-conf-pvc
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-ra
      unit: zookeeper
      parentdeployment: test-zookeeper
```

**kubectl describe** for kafka also shows exposed nodeport

```
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.233.1.106
Port:                     kafka  9092/TCP
TargetPort:               9092/TCP
NodePort:                 kafka  30092/TCP
Endpoints:                10.233.66.15:9092
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
```

I have a publisher binary that will send some messages into Kafka. As I am having a 3 node cluster deployment, I am using my primary node IP and Kafka node port (30092) to connect with the Kafka.

But my binary is getting `dial tcp <primary_node_ip>:9092: connect: connection refused` error. I am unable to understand why is it getting rejected even after nodePort to targetPort conversion is successful. With the further debugging I am seeing the following debug logs in the kafka logs:

```
[2021-01-13 08:17:51,692] DEBUG Accepted connection from /10.233.125.0:1564 on /10.233.66.15:9092 and assigned it to processor 0, sendBufferSize [actual|requested]: [102400|102400] recvBufferSize [actual|requested]: [102400|102400] (kafka.network.Acceptor)
[2021-01-13 08:17:51,692] DEBUG Processor 0 listening to new connection from /10.233.125.0:1564 (kafka.network.Processor)
[2021-01-13 08:17:51,702] DEBUG [SslTransportLayer channelId=10.233.66.15:9092-10.233.125.0:1564-245 key=sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@43dc2246] SSL peer is not authenticated, returning ANONYMOUS instead (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer)
[2021-01-13 08:17:51,702] DEBUG [SslTransportLayer channelId=10.233.66.15:9092-10.233.125.0:1564-245 key=sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@43dc2246] SSL handshake completed successfully with peerHost '10.233.125.0' peerPort 1564 peerPrincipal 'User:ANONYMOUS' cipherSuite 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256' (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer)
[2021-01-13 08:17:51,702] DEBUG [SocketServer brokerId=1001] Successfully authenticated with /10.233.125.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2021-01-13 08:17:51,707] DEBUG [SocketServer brokerId=1001] Connection with /10.233.125.0 disconnected (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.read(SslTransportLayer.java:614)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:95)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:448)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:398)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:678)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:580)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:485)
        at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:861)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:760)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

With the same configuration, I was able to expose other services. What am I missing here?

Update: When I added KAFKA_LISTENERS and KAFKA_ADV_LISTENERS for **EXTERNAL** and changed the targetPort to 30092, the error message during external connections disappeared, but started getting connection errors for internal connections.

Solution:
I exposed another service for external communication like mentioned in the answer and exposed 30092 as the port and the node port for it. So there was no requirement of targetPort. I also had to add additional KAFKA_LISTENERS and KAFKA_ADV_LISTENERS in the deployment file for external communication

Comment: Can you also share the YAML of your Kafka Deployment?

Comment: @EmruzHossain I have updated the question with the Kafka deployment yaml file. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Looks like an ssl problem. Are you using some kind of self-signed certificate?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at using Strimzi for managing Kafka on k8s

Comment: @ChristophRaab No. I am using CA signed certs.

Comment: Could you also post your zookeeper manifest?

Comment: @hdhruna added zookeeper deployment and service yaml files

Comment: your kubernetes configuration seems to be fine. By changing the `tagetPort` to 30092, you just made it worse, as there is nothing running there. Basicaly, you got the same error, but you were looking to other port. Your error must come from your kafka configuration. Are you configuring any timeouts in your broker config? You might have open connections while you are trying to open a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We faced a similar issue in one of our Kafka setups; we ended up creating two k8s services, one using ClusterIP for internal communication and second service with same labels using NodePort for external communication.

internal access

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-internal
  namespace: test
  labels:
    app: kafka-test
    unit: kafka
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: test-app
    unit: kafka
    parentdeployment: test-kafka
  ports:
    - name: kafka
      port: 9092
      protocol: TCP
  type: ClusterIP
```

external access

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-external
  namespace: test
  labels:
    app: kafka-test
    unit: kafka
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: test-app
    unit: kafka
    parentdeployment: test-kafka
  ports:
    - name: kafka
      port: 9092
      targetPort: 9092
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I tried as you said, but getting an error `dial tcp: lookup kafka on 169.254.25.10:53: server misbehaving`. Any idea why?

Comment: Is this from your internal or external connection access? Also, do you specifically want to assign NodePort 30092? If not you can remove that from the external manifest and k8s should assign another available nodeport.

Comment: I need the nodeport to be fixed. The error `server misbehaving` was because the service name was not changed to kafka-internal. Now I am getting `dial tcp: lookup kafka-external: Temporary failure in name resolution`.

Comment: Are you connecting from your binary to `kafka-external:30092` from the same host as one of the k8s nodes? or is it on a separate workstation? If later, then you will have to use `<NODE_EXTERNAL_IP>:30092`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I exposed another service for external communication like you mentioned and exposed 30092 as the port and the node port for it. So there was no requirement of targetPort.

I also had to add additional KAFKA_LISTENERS and KAFKA_ADV_LISTENERS in the deployment file for external communication